# undo sp_recompile

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have marked one stored procedure for recompilation with sp_recompile. 
syntax is

```
exec sp_recompile '[STORED PROCEDURE NAME]'
```

How can I undo this.

Comment: You can't. This command causes the server to throw away cached plans. They're gone.

Comment: Why you want to undo recompilation? It is expected to get better results with recompile. If it gets worse, then you can think of creating alternative SPs for different input parameter characteristics.

Comment: There is no documented way to do this, the recompile SP updates the internal schema version number of the procedure, the new value mismatch causes its recompilation on the next run.

Answer (score -1):

Come up to one solution

Drop and create stored procedure again. :)

Comment: And at that point, the next time that the procedure is executed, a new plan has to be compiled - which is exactly what `sp_recompile` was forcing to happen. You haven't "undone" anything. You've just added some extra steps and ended up at exactly the state you were in anyway.

Comment: So what was your problem? You still haven't described that anywhere, and without it this question isn't useful for anyone else.